# Videos loading with 206 - Partial Content

Tags: video, http-headers, cache-control

I'm having a problem loading videos - they are all returning with a 206 (Partial Content) response. I'd like to fire an event when they are 100%, but it's not getting there.

Here's what I get in the inspector:

**Response Headers**

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:12465963
Content-Length:12465963
Content-Range:bytes 0-12465962/12465963
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Wed, 01 Apr 2015 00:26:29 GMT
ETag:"6f23fd3-be372b-51239e2090e70"
Host-Header:192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024
Last-Modified:Fri, 27 Mar 2015 00:04:58 GMT
Server:Apache
X-Cache:SGCACHE-MISS
X-Forwarded-For:189.135.253.115
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=ml8n0hh37na09ggjcvvbeld383; key=76626f47b940e09d3601920b684befc62d703fd5%2Bda9d8d1ede4727d1486ac7274487ffa8994d18f3%7C1427415309%7Ce2fa179955ca0ce759d4ba10c1227e825bba261f%7CZGV2YWRtaW4%3D
DNT:1
Host:[xxxxx]
Pragma:no-cache
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:[xxxxx]
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36
```

I saw this: `Content-Range:bytes 0-12465962/12465963` - and noticed that it has loaded all but the last byte.

**Secondary question**: I also see `Cache-Control:no-cache`. The videos I'm loading aren't large, and it would be nice to keep them in the cache for a short amount of time.

I'm clueless when it comes to headers and this kind of thing. What's going on?

Answer (score 5):

As long as you set `Range:bytes=0-` in the request, you will have a 206 response. `0-` means start at byte zero, and give me all bytes to the end of the file. And the server is doing exactly that. You are in fact receiving all the bytes, including the last byte. `Content-Range:bytes 0-12465962/12465963` is inclusive. The first byte is at position 0, the second byte at position 1, etc. So 0-12465962 is 12465963 bytes total.